# python/django create a text file and make user download it

Tags: python, django

does anyone know if there is a way to create a text file who can be downloaded by an user of my django site ? Can someone help me or send me tutorials to show me how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a file with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441882/download-a-file-with-django)

Answer (score 0):

Donsimething like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def download_view(request):
   
   file_data = your_textfile 
   response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/text charset=utf-8')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="testfile.txt"'
   return response
```